# APDU sequence to read ICC card records failing on selection of application by AID (giving a response of SWA SWB 6283)

Tags: icc, apdu, emv, iso-7816-4

I am having trouble reading ICC data from an card. I have an AID from an issuer which is A0000007790000. So I am sending an APDU of 00A4040007A0000007790000 to select the application by its AID but I keep getting response of SWA: 62 SWB: 83. What am I missing, and how can I proceed from there.

I can only do a select PSE using 00A404000E315041592E5359532E444446303100 which is successful and I am getting a response of 6F1A840E315041592E5359532E4444463031A5088801015F2D02656E..
The Other commands like 00B2010C00 are returning that SWA SWB 6283 (Selected file invalidated) response. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the full reply to Select PSE command.

Comment: T6F1A840E315041592E5359532E4444463031A5088801015F2D02656ESWA:90 SWB:00 Thats the Select PSE response

Answer (score 1):

The AID Select Command should have additional **Le** byte.

APDU Command: `00A4040007 A000000779 0000 00`

Comment: Okay,, let me add that and see how it goes

Comment: I have added that byte to make it 00A4040007 A000000779 0000 00, I am getiing the same response. I also tried using 00A4040007 A000000779 0000 01 Still I am getting SWA SWB 6283.

Comment: Please ensure you card is personalized and ready to work to follow the EMV transaction APDU sequence.

Comment: I am sure it is, I can actually get track2 data from MCR on the card,,What does 6283 mean, From my research I was getting that it means  the application is blocked, Is that correct?

Comment: I even use that card to transact using that chip functionality on other POS terminals

Comment: First it is a bit strange that you have app block status on read record during PSE processing, but a normal payment device will simply fall back to List of Applications method. Are you sure there is not a different AID that a terminal uses?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I had was on the device permissions, I had not realized that the device I was using to read the emv cards had no permissions to read external files, so that did not allow me to read any data from the application files in the chip card